# point-wise approximation of the identity in hereditary Lindelof spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, measure-theory, banach-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological ***vector***  space. Assume that there exists a sequence of finite range measurable functions $\phi_n:X\to X$ with $\lim\phi_n(x)=x$.

Q. Can we concluded that $X$ is hereditery Lindelof?

By an interesting example *Taras Banakh* proved that: $X$ is not necessarily written by countable union of second countable subsets (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300729/approximation-of-the-identity-by-finite-range-functions-in-topological-vector-sp)).

Comment: I think that the free (locally convex) linear topological space over the Sorgenfrey line will be a counterexample and encourage Ali Bagheri to try to prove this fact himself.